# Expression undefined in a template literal after -

Tags: javascript, expression, template-literals

Here is the part of the url I have an issue with : `&lang=ru-${lang}`
The template literal `${lang}` will give undefined because of the - after ru.
I tried to `console.log(lang)` and `console.log(${lang})` both give me the string `fr` so the problem won't come from the function parameter.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

EDIT : some context

```js
class Translate {
    constructor(text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    async getTranslations(lang) {
        const url = `https://site/api/v1/apiKey&lang=ru-${lang}&text=${this.text}&flags=004`;
        
        console.log(url);
        
        const response = await fetch(url);
        return await response.json();
    }
}

const oWord = 'oWord';
const translate = new Translate(oWord);
translate.getTranslations('fr');
```

Comment: > The template literal ${lang} will give undefined because of the - after ru. -- no that's not how that works. what exactly is the output, and show us the code around it.

Comment: Sorry for the lake of context, I edited my first post

Comment: It's not enough. We need to see where you assign the lang variable.

Comment: I ran your code in the console and it worked, the URL I received is :  https://site/api/v1/apiKey&lang=ru-fr&text=oWord&flags=004

Comment: No. There is literally no way, that `${lang}` will give undefined if you pass value `'fr'` for `lang`. It does not matter wheter there is a `-` or not. Of course `${ru}` will give undefined because there is no variable named `ru`. And `console.log(${ru})` will give a syntax error

Comment: @derpirscher I'm sorry I meant console.log(${lang}) works fine and give me fr. When I remove the - it give me fr in the url and not undefined anymore.

Comment: No, also console.log(${lang}) will give you a syntax error.  And again, there is no way that the code shown above will produce any undefined values within url. Please post the output of `console.log(url)` after you assigned it.

Comment: console.log(${lang}) with ${lang} in template literals, can't render them correctly here...

Comment: I edited your question into a code snippet. As you can see, the url correctly contains `&lang=ru-fr` as expected ...

Comment: ok I think there is some conflict in my code, I will try to fix it out, thank you

Comment: Well, if you'd posted your exact code that shows the problem, we would probably be able to help you ...

Comment: @derpirscher I isolated my class and all is working fine now. I will try to understand where the conflict comes from. I should have done it before, Sorry for I made you lose your time but anyway you helped me a lot. Thanks !